# dashlet creation

Tags: dashboard

I have been asked if it is possible to create a 'team info' dashlet that can be used for getting info to everyone in the team when they log on to CiviCRM at the start of each working day. Any ideas as to how to do this would be welcome. The organisation concerned is using CiviCRM 4.6.33 and Joomla 3.8.3

Comment: You would have to explain what you expect on the 'team info' dashlet before you can expect a really helpfull answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a dashlet, you are just giving the url or a page without any "chrome" (navigation menu, side columns, footers..) Just the content to be displayed.

If you can produce such minimal html section for your team info, you should be able to have it displayed in a dashlet.

Check out the news dashlet, it's basically what it does